# Audio not playing on Flutter web app through firebase

Tags: flutter, web

```
    import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
// ...
final player = AudioPlayer();
await player.play(UrlSource('images/notification.mp3'));
```

this is working on the local chrome browser

but when I deployed to firebase, then the sound is not playing

Comment: Hello, did you solve this?  I have the same problem.   I found a posting elsewhere that suggested that this is something to do with the media file format, and that you have to configure Firesbase to support mp3, but I can't find anything to configure in the Firebase UI